# Tomcat shutdown hook

Tags: spray

I'm trying to implement a shutdown hook in a tomcat web app where i have little control. Basically, i have implemented a lib, that use spray rest client, based on actor. I have tried the typical shutdown hook of spray but it did not works. Worst it says that the access to the actor system is illegal, as if everything was shutdown already.

I was wondering if there is specific to tomcat if one wants to call:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

    override def run() {
      println("shutting down spray")
      IO(Http) ! Http.CloseAll
      IO(Http) ! PoisonPill
      system.shutdown();
    }
  })
```

Comment: I might have got your question wrong. Are you only using spray-client? Or are you also using spray-servlet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do this.

You should have registered `spray.servlet.Initializer` as a `ServletContextListener` in your `web.xml`.

This is how `spray.servlet.Initializer` overrides `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed` copied from [github.com/spray/spray](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/scala/spray/servlet/Initializer.scala)

```
@volatile private[this] var actorSystem: Option[ActorSystem] = None

...

def contextDestroyed(e: ServletContextEvent): Unit = {
  booted switchOff {
    println("Shutting down spray application ...")
    actorSystem.foreach(_.shutdown())
    actorSystem.foreach(_.awaitTermination())
  }
}
```

See also [spray-servlet documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-servlet/#starting-and-stopping).